# Is there a RabbitMQ pattern for a client election

Tags: rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

Is there a way to have a pub/sub queue in RabbitMq in which any of the subscribers could vote and all give a thumbs up (or more importantly a thumbs down) before processing continues?

I am not sure what to call this so It is very hard to research.

I am trying to make subscribers that can be added and have the ability to veto a process without knowing about them up front.

{edit below}

I am essentially trying to build a distributed set of services that could filter in very specific use cases as they are discovered.  I am trying to do this so I do not have to down my service and version every time one of these new use cases is discovered.

Here is a contrived example but it gets the point across:

Lets say I want to calculate if a number is Prime.
I would like to have a service that has general easy rules, (is factor of 2? is factor of 3?)

But lets say that we are getting into very large numbers, and I find a new algorithm that is faster for finding specific cases.

I would like to be able to add this service, have it subscribe to the feed and be able to trigger "NotPrime" and have all other subscribers abandon their work as a result of the veto.

In a monolithic world I would look at some sort of plug in framework and have that implement the filters.  That seems like mixing strategies in a bad way if were to do the same within a micro service.

Comment: What problem are you hoping to solve with this?

Comment: I am trying to build something that will allow me to add filters as microservices so I do not have to down my entire service for any additional filters that arrive.